# Why is ubuntu 11.04 not shipping with mono 2.8

Tags: 11.04, mono

Mono 2.8 was released on the 22nd August 2010 this is before ubuntu 10.10 was released however ubuntu 11.04 is shipping with mono 2.6 which is really very old now.

Why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by shipping? why ubuntu doesn't include mono package in it's installation CD or why updated Mono (version 2.8) isn't given on the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Novell who is the major sponsor of mono has chosen not to provide Ubuntu packages. The packages used in Ubuntu come from the community. The Community has not yet packaged ubuntu 2.8 and so ubuntu 11.04 is stuck using the old mono 2.6 packages.

Maybe this is a solution

http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/10/mono-2-8-install-script-for-ubuntu-fedora/

Comment: ubuntu represents a very large portion, (perhaps the largest portion) of mono's user base any idea why Novell has chosen not to support it.

Comment: -1: Mono is opensource, it's no more a Novell product than openoffice was a sun product, or even Ubuntu is a Canonical product. It can be packaged as any other program. This is not a valid reason.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page -> Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily create cross platform applications. Sponsored by ***Novell*** (http://www.novell.com/), Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. A growing family of solutions and an active and enthusiastic contributing community is helping position Mono to become the leading choice for development of Linux applications.    Maybe product was not the right word but i did it in "" ...

Comment: I know Novell are the main drivers of Mono. But how is it related to not shipping it?. It's open source. Source Code is available. Under a free license. It can be packaged. It's no different than OpenOffice was, it's no different than the kernel.

Comment: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html  mono 2.8 packages for suse are available - for other distros it is a community effort -> i think because novell doesn't support ubuntu there will be no official mono 2.8 packages for ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Much better wording now ;). All the distributions make their own packages for their repos. It's not expected from the developer of an open source project to package it for all the distros. Plus most of the distros customize important packages. Finally, mono is in the main repo, that usually means that Canonical not the community packages it.

Answer (score 5):

The Debian Mono Group packages Mono for both Debian and Ubuntu. Our focus is on providing a quality and stable experience for users. This does not always mean having the latest version available at all times. Remember that Mono is also the basis for a large number of applications, including some which are in the default install. It's therefore critical that it functions as well as possible. Basically “new” isn't always what is best for the distribution.

Furthermore, packaging and QAing a major upstream revision is a huge effort, and as the team is comprised entirely of volunteers, this has to be done when time presents itself.

The groundwork towards making 2.10 available (rc1 was recently released) is under way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my stability argument is not invalid. I didn't say that 2.10~rc1 was going to be included in the distribution, did I? I simply said that work /towards/ making it available /when it is released/ is underway. This is a fact. I made no promises about when it will be available.

Comment: @trampster Unfortunately this is the best answer you're going to get; it is a ton of work to transition major parts of the platform and the Mono team is entirely volunteers and does it for 2 OSes; sometimes skipping a release is the best thing to do given the amount of people and time.

Comment: If anyone wants to help the team here's the mailing list: http://lists.debian.org/debian-cli/

Comment: could you remove the 2.10 comment or at least make it clear this is not intended for 11.04 seeing as the question is about 11.04

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 11.04, with mono 2.6.7 - see http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu

To get the latest ironpython 2.7.1 working, I have to update mono.

So I install mono 2.10.5, nicely build by Jo Shields on http://badgerports.org/

He said it is for ubuntu 10.04, but knowing from the first link that 10.04 and 11.04 both used mono 2.6.7, I try the update and bingo ! no errors, and ironpython starts :

```
mono ../IronPython-2.7.1/ipy.exe
IronPython 2.7.1 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.1
```